# Is it possible to scroll above/under an element with scroll to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple menu that scrolls to a section when a menu item is clicked.

For example:

```
<li><a href="#contact" class="menu_item">Contact</a></li>
```

Will scroll to:

```
<section id="contact"></section>
```

However I've also got a menu that always sticks to the top, and the height of that menu is not calculated with the scroll script. So the menu always hovers over the top part of an element, making part of it unreadable.

How can I change it so that it scrolls not directly to that element, but let's say 80px above it? And preferable only for one element, since I've only got this issue for one section on my page.

I am using this scroll to element script:

```
/* Scroll to Main Menu
        ================================================== */
        $('#navigation a[href*=#]').click( function(event) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var offset = -80;
            if($this.parent().is(':nth-child(2)')) {
                offset = 2; // for second child dont do offset
            };
            $.scrollTo( $this.attr('href') , 650, { easing: 'swing' , offset: offset , 'axis':'y' } );
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        /* Scroll to Element on Page
        ================================================== */
        $('a#to-blog').click( function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.scrollTo( $('#blog') , 1250, {  offset: 1 , 'axis':'y' } );
        });

         $('.hero-btn').click( function(event) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var offset = -80;
            if($this.attr('href') == '#about-us' || $('.nomenu').is(':visible')) {
                offset = 0; // for first section dont do offset
            };
            $.scrollTo( $this.attr('href') , 650, { easing: 'swing' , offset: offset , 'axis':'y' } );
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        /* Add active class for each nav depending on scroll
        ================================================== */
        $('section').each(function() {
            $(this).waypoint( function( direction ) {
                if( direction === 'down' ) {
                    var containerID = $(this).attr('id');
                    /* update navigation */
                    $('#navigation a').removeClass('active');
                    $('#navigation a[href*=#'+containerID+']').addClass('active');
                }
            } , { offset: '80px' } );

            $(this).waypoint( function( direction ) {
                if( direction === 'up' ) {
                    var containerID = $(this).attr('id');
                    /* update navigation */
                    $('#navigation a').removeClass('active');
                    $('#navigation a[href*=#'+containerID+']').addClass('active');
                }          
            } , { offset: function() { return -$(this).height() - 80; } });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the offset in the various places to the value you want:

`var offset = -80;`

A lesser number will be further "up" the page, a higher number will be further "down" the page.

Comment: I tried that, but I don't know which one it is. Or maybe a combination of a few?

Comment: I see 3 different scrollTo definitions in the script, which one is causing the problem?

Comment: The scripts work fine, only I want to know how to change the  position it scrolls to a little.

Comment: You change the position via the offset parameter.  You mentioned that only one link is not scrolling where you want.  Which link is it, as defined in the javascript you provided?